# Editing a ComboBox in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, combobox

I am having problems editing a ComboBox in AS3.  Can anyone please tell me why my ComboBox disappears?  Thanks to all that help in advance.

---

```
import fl.controls.ComboBox;
import fl.data.DataProvider;


var typeTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
typeTextFormat.color = 0xFFCC00;
typeTextFormat.size = 11;
typeTextFormat.font = "Verdana";


var typeButton:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(typeButton);
typeButton.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
typeButton.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 109, 32);
typeButton.graphics.endFill();
typeButton.alpha = 0.75;
typeButton.filters = [new GlowFilter(0x000000,0.5,0,12,1,1,false,false)];


var workList:Array = new Array(
    { label: "All Work", data: "all" },
        { label: "Work1", data: "w1" },
        { label: "Work2", data: "w2" },
        { label: "Work3", data: "w3" }
    );


var menu1:ComboBox = new ComboBox();
addChild(menu1);

menu1.setStyle("upSkin", typeButton);
menu1.setStyle("overSkin", typeButton);
menu1.setStyle("downSkin", typeButton);
menu1.setSize(109, 32);

menu1.dropdown.setRendererStyle("upSkin", typeButton);
menu1.dropdown.setRendererStyle("overSkin", typeButton);
menu1.dropdown.setRendererStyle("downSkin", typeButton);
menu1.dropdown.setSize(109, 32);

menu1.textField.setStyle("textFormat", typeTextFormat);
menu1.move(120, 0);
menu1.prompt = "All Work";
menu1.dataProvider = new DataProvider(workList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I have found out the answer.  Well half of it!  I now have two Sprites, both the same in shape but called typeButton and dropButton.  These are both added to the parent menu1 and menu1.dropdown respectively.  I no longer get the disappearing problem.  So this works fine... for a bit... but after clicking around for a bit I eventually get Argument Error: 2025 and my limited knowledge comes up against a brick wall...

```
import fl.data.DataProvider;
import fl.controls.ComboBox;

var typeTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
typeTextFormat.color = 0xFFCC00;
typeTextFormat.size = 11;
typeTextFormat.font = "Verdana";

var menu1:ComboBox = new ComboBox();
addChild(menu1);

var typeButton:Sprite = new Sprite();
menu1.addChild(typeButton);
typeButton.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
typeButton.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 109, 34);
typeButton.graphics.endFill();
typeButton.alpha = 0.75;
typeButton.filters = [new DropShadowFilter(3,120,0x000000,0.5,0,0,1,1,false,false,false)];

var dropButton:Sprite = new Sprite();
menu1.dropdown.addChild(dropButton);
dropButton.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
dropButton.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 109, 34);
dropButton.graphics.endFill();
dropButton.alpha = 0.75;
dropButton.filters = [new DropShadowFilter(3,120,0x000000,0.5,0,0,1,1,false,false,false)];

menu1.setStyle("upSkin", typeButton);
menu1.setStyle("overSkin", typeButton);
menu1.setStyle("downSkin", typeButton);
menu1.setSize(109, 34);

menu1.dropdown.setRendererStyle("upSkin", dropButton);
menu1.dropdown.setRendererStyle("overSkin", dropButton);
menu1.dropdown.setRendererStyle("downSkin", dropButton);
menu1.dropdown.setSize(109, 34);

menu1.textField.setStyle("textFormat", typeTextFormat);
menu1.dropdown.setRendererStyle("textFormat", typeTextFormat);
menu1.move(120, 0);
menu1.prompt = "All Work";
var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider();
dp.addItem( { label: "All Work", data: "all" } );
dp.addItem( { label: "Work1", data: "w1" } );
dp.addItem( { label: "Work2", data: "w2" } );
dp.addItem( { label: "Work3", data: "w3" } );
menu1.dataProvider = dp;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider();
dp.addItem( { label: "All Work", data: "all" } );
dp.addItem( { label: "Work1", data: "w1" } );
dp.addItem( { label: "Work2", data: "w2" } );
dp.addItem( { label: "Work3", data: "w3" } );

menu1.dataProvider = dp;
```

[EDIT]
Working code in cs4

```
import fl.data.DataProvider;
import fl.controls.ComboBox

var typeTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
typeTextFormat.color = 0xFFCC00;
typeTextFormat.size = 11;
typeTextFormat.font = "Verdana";


var typeButton:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(typeButton);
typeButton.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
typeButton.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 109, 32);
typeButton.graphics.endFill();
typeButton.alpha = 0.75;
typeButton.filters = [new GlowFilter(0x000000,0.5,0,12,1,1,false,false)];


var menu1:ComboBox = new ComboBox();
addChild(menu1);

menu1.setStyle("upSkin", typeButton);
menu1.setStyle("overSkin", typeButton);
menu1.setStyle("downSkin", typeButton);
menu1.setSize(109, 32);

menu1.dropdown.setRendererStyle("upSkin", typeButton);
menu1.dropdown.setRendererStyle("overSkin", typeButton);
menu1.dropdown.setRendererStyle("downSkin", typeButton);
menu1.dropdown.setSize(109, 32);

menu1.textField.setStyle("textFormat", typeTextFormat);
menu1.move(120, 0);
menu1.prompt = "All Work";
var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider();
dp.addItem( { label: "All Work", data: "all" } );
dp.addItem( { label: "Work1", data: "w1" } );
dp.addItem( { label: "Work2", data: "w2" } );
dp.addItem( { label: "Work3", data: "w3" } );
menu1.dataProvider = dp;
```

[EDIT 2]
Ok, now that I see what issues your are having.
It seems your issue is with the following lines

```
menu1.dropdown.setRendererStyle("upSkin", typeButton);
menu1.dropdown.setRendererStyle("overSkin", typeButton);
menu1.dropdown.setRendererStyle("downSkin", typeButton);
```

Apparently, the combobox dropdown is list based and as such uses an item renderer.
So you have to set the skin through the renderer.

```
comboBox.dropdown.itemRenderer = "someItemRender.as";
```

I also ran across this [site.](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=163793) but, I could not get it to work, although the idea seems to be solid.

Comment: Thanks The_asMan but the same problem still occurs.

Comment: I copied your code that you posted in a fresh flash document and made my changes and it worked fine. Are you not posting something?

Comment: I just made a new program to test your code.  The problem I get with your code is still the same problem I came across with mine.  At the beginning the ComboBox is visible.  So far so good.  When you click on the ComboBox is visible too.  Still good.  But as soon as you roll out it disappears (minus the TextField).  It also becomes inactive.  I am using Flash CS5 by the way.  Any ideas?

Comment: Edited my answer. Your cell rendering is what is breaking it. If you comment out the lines menu1.dropdown.setRendererStyle you will see it works fine.